# How to do an association plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a table with two categorical values and I want to visualise their association; the number of times that they are found together in the same row.

For instance, let's take this data frame:

```
d <-data.frame(cbind(sample(1:5,100,replace=T),  sample(1:10,100,replace=T)))
```

How can generate a heatmap like this:

[image]

Where the colour of the squares represent the number of times that X1 and X2 are found in a given combination.

It would be even better to know how to plot this with a dot plot instead, where the size of the dot represent the count of the combination occurrence between X1 and X2.

If you can guide me how to do this on ggplot2 or any other way in R, it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
d <-data.frame(x = sample(1:5,100,replace=T), y = sample(1:10,100,replace=T))
d_sum <- d %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```

For the heatmap:

```
ggplot(d_sum, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = count))
```

[image]

For the dotplot:

```
ggplot(d_sum, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = count))
```

[image]

Comment: It works totally smooth, this was exactly what I was asking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
set.seed(123)
d <-data.frame(x = sample(1:20,1000,replace=T), y = sample(1:20,1000,replace=T))
d %>% count(x, y) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = n)) +  
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:20)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:20)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='white', mid='steelblue', high='red') + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend("Count")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]